# Not work my function after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I not know why not work following code for my function(`alert()`) and is run my function(`alert()`) after tow times click on button, did you can guide me?

**Demo:(Here see my full code)** http://jsfiddle.net/pRXQ7/1/

```
$('.iu').click(function() {
    if(alert() == true){
        alert('ok')
    }else{
        alert('no')
    }
});
```

Comment: `wan\'t` - wth. it's `want` ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But calling your own method `alert()` is probably a Bad Idea.

Comment: Your creating a function named alert() but javascript already has an alert function. Some strange use of variables, and how do you check if a function is true without even running it?

Comment: OK, why after tow click it is run?

Comment: The code RoccoC5 posted works perfectly...you can see the mistakes you did and I didn't see it working even after 'n' clicks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By naming your function `alert`, you've effectively overridden the native javascript `alert` function.  Name it something else.

Also, in your `alert` function, you are referencing `this`. In the scope of the function, `this` points to the document object, not the element which was clicked. Try passing the element instance to your function from the click event handler.

See http://jsfiddle.net/pRXQ7/15/